# Can't adapt the type set as a programming error

Tags: python, postgresql, set

I receive an error that says can't adapt type 'set' I am trying to insert my script into the postgres database.

```
def batchInsert(conn, circuits, page_size: int = 585):
    '''
    batch insert of circuit dataframe into Postgres slow_operators.preprocessed
    '''
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        query = """INSERT INTO slow_operators.preprocessed VALUES %s"""
        psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cursor, query,
                                   (v[1:] for v in circuits.itertuples()),
                                   page_size=page_size)
    conn.commit()

print('importing into postgres {}'.format(dt.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
print('insert via batch insert at {}'.format(dt.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
batchInsert(pgis.raw_connection(), circuits)
```

Comment: The code and error you provide are not detailed enough for anyone to give you help. Your code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- something we can cut and paste and run directly. If you are getting an error or exception, you should copy and paste the exact message into your question. And finally, for a question that is related to a database, you should provide some information on the table structure and data types.

Comment: Reading the docs would be a good start [Python type adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types).